# Find delivery date in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a calendar with delivery dates for the whole year. The rule is simple - the delivery requires at least 2 business and special days from the order date.

```
index   order_date  business_day    special_day     delivery_date
0       2021-01-01  0               0               2021-01-05  
1       2021-01-02  0               0               2021-01-05
2       2021-01-03  0               0               2021-01-05
3       2021-01-04  1               1               2021-01-06
4       2021-01-05  1               1               2021-01-07
5       2021-01-06  1               1               ???
```

I thought that I need to pass a function that has access to both axes but I have no idea how to do it.

```
df['delivery_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: getDeliveryDate(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: Pandas have a business day function. You should probably use it: `pandas.tseries.offsets.BDay`

Comment: I have updated the question. The business day is just one of the criteria.